# swiftui ios15 keyboard avoidance issue on custom textfield

Tags: swiftui, keyboard, overlay, textfield, ios15

Repost question from this [Adjust View up with Keyboard show in SwiftUI 3.0 iOS15](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69917104/19445281).

SwiftUI keyboard avoidance won't show the whole textfield including the overlay.

I already tried a lot different ways from googling.
Does anyone have any solution for this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Spacer(minLength: 600)
                TextField("Placeholder", text: $text)
                    .textFieldStyle(CustomTextFieldStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .padding(10)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 5)
            )
    }
}
```

[image: Image Preview]

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the custom `UITextFeild`, in which the `intrinsicContentSize` will be overridden.

Example:

```swift
final class _UITextField: UITextField {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: 56)
    }
}
```

Then, you can write your own implementation of TextField, using `UIViewRepresentable` protocol and `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```swift
struct _TextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let title: String?
    @Binding var text: String

    let textField = _UITextField()

    init(
        _ title: String?,
        text: Binding<String>
    ) {
        self.title = title
        self._text = text
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> _TextFieldCoordinator {
        _TextFieldCoordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> _UITextField {
        textField.placeholder = title
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: _UITextField, context: Context) {}
}

final class _TextFieldCoordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
    private let control: _TextField

    init(_ control: _TextField) {
        self.control = control
        super.init()
        control.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldEditingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    @objc private func textFieldEditingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        control.text = textField.text ?? ""
    }
}
```